# VS2015 Community ASP.NET5 Dependency injection and azure publish errors after UWP update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2015

Until recently i had working asp.net 5 mvc webapi project. It worked locally and i was able to push it to azure cloud (publish option).
About week ago i started to work on universal windows app for rasberry pi 3 - so i installed necessary package (Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps) with couple more updates from gallery (new version for ASP.NET and Web Tools probably).
When i got back to working on webapi project i've noticed warnings:

> DOTNET1015    The 'compilationOptions' option is deprecated. Use
>   'buildOptions' instead.
>
> DOTNET1015    The 'exclude' option is deprecated. Use 'exclude' within
>   'compile' or 'embed' instead.
>
> DOTNET1015    The 'publishExclude' option is deprecated. Use
>   'publishOptions' instead.

in my `project.json` file
So something must have changed after those updates.
Project build passes but when i start it locally on debug and IIS Express i get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
>
> Additional information: No service for type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.IApplicationEnvironment'
>   has been registered.

And when i try tu push it to azure i get some errors in my language (polish) about metabase problems and wrong format of paths eg. lm/w3svc//ROOT/

my `project.json` file: http://pastebin.pl/view/f823f093

VS info: http://pastebin.pl/view/86bae236

I try to clean and rebuild solution, restore packages but its probably something else. 
What can i do except of uninstalling VS and instaling one more time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete uninstall of VS 2015 Comunity and clean install of `AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909` did the trick for me. Problematic update probably was
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935?SRC=VSIDE